# Tab history in Google Chrome is limited to only 6 items

Tags: google-chrome, history

When I reopen the last session in Goole Chrome and long press the back button on each tab, I can see only 6 items in the drop-down list. I remember the times when it had more than 30 items. How can I increase this number, or even make it unlimited?

Comment: Hello, which Chrome version do you use?

Comment: Sorry, I missed your question. It's 109.0.5414.141 (Official Build) (64-bit) - the latest version for Windows 8.1.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe that this can be changed. You could ask for it as
a feature request on the Chrome forums.

These extensions could perhaps help with the problem.
(Unfortunately I have no experience with either of them.)

[**Tabs Backup & Restore**](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tabs-backup-restore/dehocbglhkaogiljpihicakmlockmlgd/reviews?hl=et)

> Backup an entire Chrome session (all opened windows and tabs) and
> restore it when needed.
>
> Backups are created automatically (every XX minutes, definable in the
> Options Page), but can also be created manually whenever you want.

[**Recent Tabs with your browsing history**](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/recent-tabs-with-your-bro/khjgklaeknnibmeeanmbfjcnjablcpil?hl=pt)

> Extension to restore recently closed tabs. The mechanism is similar to
> Chrome's built-in functions "Recent Tabs" (Ctrl-Shift-T). In the
> restored tab kept the entire history of browsing, ie, The buttons Back
> and Forward.